# Comparing datetime variable to null always gives false

Tags: apex, date, datetime

I am trying to compare a datetime field with value to null even if I compare both of them it always gives false

The code I am running

```
Datetime a;
Datetime yesterday = Datetime.now().addDays(-1);
System.debug(a);
System.debug(yesterday.date());
System.debug(yesterday<a);
System.debug(yesterday>a);
```

It strangely give debug logs as follows

```
15:15:19:002 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|null
15:15:19:002 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|2017-08-23 00:00:00
15:15:19:002 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|false
15:15:19:002 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|false
```

I cannot find any possible reason for this can anyone help me with this.

Comment: "Nothing" is nor greater nor smaller than "something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as intended, as stated on [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm)

> Unlike other database stored procedures, Apex does not support tri-state Boolean logic, and the comparison of any two values can never result in null.
>
> **If x or y equal null and are Integers, Doubles, Dates, or Datetimes, the expression is false.**
>
> A non-null String or ID value is always greater than a null value.
>
> If x and y are IDs, they must reference the same type of object. Otherwise, a runtime error results.
>
> If x or y is an ID and the other value is a String, the String value is validated and treated as an ID.
>   x and y cannot be Booleans.
>
> The comparison of two strings is performed according to the locale of the context user and is case-insensitive.

Emphasis mine