# SOQL returns data even if bind apex variable is null

Tags: soql, customsetting

We have a public custom settings **Batch_Settings__c** of type Hierarchy (Organisation level) and it has a date/time field called "Last_Run__c".

The field **Last_Run__c** is null, but SOQL filtered on this date still returns data.
We have this issue both when executing SOQL from Execute Anonymous script or from batch apex.

API version: 46

[image]

Refer to this sample script to illustrate this issue.

```
Batch_Settings__c settings =  Batch_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
system.debug('settings.Last_Run__c = '+ settings.Last_Run__c); //settings.Last_Run__c = null
List<Contact> contactList = [select id, name from contact 
                         where LastModifiedDate >= :settings.Last_Run__c limit 5];                        
system.debug('contactList.size= '+contactList.size()); //size=5
system.debug('contactList= '+contactList);
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOQL statement works well as for your expectation. The condition is not restrictive because if "**Last Run**" is null the condition "**where LastModifiedDate >= :settings.Last_Run__c**" is always true for each record. This behaviour is not documented anywhere (I searched a lot...).

What is well documented is the behaviour of the comparison operator agaist NULL value for DateTime data type in the Apex code as explained [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189763/comparing-datetime-variable-to-null-always-gives-false) and it works in the opposite way returning always false.

I suggest you to check the value of the "**Last_Run__c**" field before the SOQL statement and perform the expected behavior in case of Null value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you have any link to official SF documentation to support this explanation ? if you run this SOQL `select id, name from Contact where LastModifiedDate >= null limit 5` in query editor (outside of apex) then it generates an error `ERROR at Row:1:Column:36 invalid operator`. so am wondering why different behavior from apex

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, actually there is no documentation for the behavior of the "where" condition, posted by you, in a SOQL statement with binding variables. My opinion is that it's possible to compare a Datetime field with null value (with the >,<,>=,<= operators) only with binding variable also within an Apex transaction otherwise you receive a runtime error (as mentioned by you). Probably this is not the expected behavior but a not managed use case.

Comment: I reached out to support and unfortunately I could not get a clear answer but they also informed that this behavior is not well documented. But based on your research this statement makes sense : "A non-null String or ID value is always greater than a null value" so this explains why the SOQL query returns result in apex.